# Django Model to manipulate LDAP Entry

Tags: ldap, django

I am currently working on a project involving **Django** framework and **OpenLDAP**. But i ran into a problem.

In my LDAP database, I have a entry named Accounts, with the following attributes:

```
dn: ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: Accounts
member: cn=test1,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro
member: cn=test2,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro
member: cn=test3,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro
... (and so on, about 10 test users)
```

In order to manipulate my LDAP entries from Django Models, I use **django_ldapdb** python package. In **models.py** file in django I defined the following things:

```
class LDAPEntry():
    base_dn = "ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro"
    object_classes = ["groupOfNames"]

    group_name = CharField(db_column="cn", primary_key=True)
    member_attribute = CharField(db_column="member")

    # methods for displaying the group name(__str__ & __unicode__)
```

After that, I open up a Django Shell, and start playing around with some queries:

```
#this returns a instance for the Accounts group
group = LDAPEntry.objects.get(group_name = "Accounts")

#then i try to see the members that are part of this group
group.member

# and this returns the following thing:
u'cn=test1,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=ro'
```

After noticing this, I realize that the member field, in my Django Model, has information about only the first member attribute in my LDAP Accounts entry, in LDAP database.

What I want to ask is: is there a possible way in which I can tell a Django Model Field to hold multiple values? ( i want my "member" field to hold information about all the member in Account Group, basically holding all the Distingueshed Names of the users).

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, and it sounds like it could be useful to other people, but, is this an ubuntu question? Should this be migrated to a different SE site?

Comment: Actually, I think you are right. And I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the situation can be resolved by changing:

```
member_attribute = CharField(db_column="member")
```

to:

```
member_attribute = ListField(db_column="member")
```

And by this all the **member** values in **Accounts** entry are fetched.